# Unable to add two parents in swagger

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui

I have some routes and I want to organize them with nested tags.
I created two interfaces that should be the parents along with the childs.

```
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.OpenAPIDefinition;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.extensions.Extension;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.extensions.ExtensionProperty;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.tags.Tag;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@OpenAPIDefinition(
        tags = {
                @Tag(name = "Admin", description = "Responsible with support. The api can be accessed " +
                        "only by the authenticated admin"),
                @Tag(name = "Manage users", description = "Managing and switch user roles.", extensions = {
                        @Extension(name = "x-tagGroups", properties = {
                                @ExtensionProperty(name = "parents", value = "Admin")
                        })
                }),
                @Tag(name = "Manage emails", description = "Managing recruiters.", extensions = {
                        @Extension(name = "x-tagGroups", properties = {
                                @ExtensionProperty(name = "parents", value = "Admin")
                        })
                })
        }
)
public @interface AdminOperation {
}
```

and

```
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.OpenAPIDefinition;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.extensions.Extension;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.extensions.ExtensionProperty;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.tags.Tag;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@OpenAPIDefinition(
        tags = {
                @Tag(name = "User", description = "The user logged on platform. The api can be accessed " +
                        "only by the authenticated user"),
                @Tag(name = "Init", description = "Register an user.", extensions = {
                        @Extension(name = "x-tagGroups", properties = {
                                @ExtensionProperty(name = "parents", value = "User")
                        })
                }),
                @Tag(name = "Attributes", description = "Managing user information.", extensions = {
                        @Extension(name = "x-tagGroups", properties = {
                                @ExtensionProperty(name = "parents", value = "User")
                        })
                }),
                @Tag(name = "Resume", description = "Managing user resume.", extensions = {
                        @Extension(name = "x-tagGroups", properties = {
                                @ExtensionProperty(name = "parents", value = "User")
                        })
                })
        }
)
public @interface UserOperation {
}
```

But still I can only see a parent in swagger ui, but not both. How can I see both or multiple parents in order to organize them better?

Thanks!